# Помогите с sql запросом из трех таблиц

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый вечер!

Есть три таблицы:

```
users(user_id int),
deps (dep_id int)
```

и соединительная:

```
depusers (user_id int, dep_id int, data int).
```

Хочу получить список всех `user_id, dep_id, count (data)` из соединительной таблицы. Если данных по `user` или для `dep` нет - вывести `null`. Понимаю что нужно полное объединение, но что-то не получается.

Comment: Что значит "что-то не получается"? Покажите ваш код и полный текст возникающей ошибки.

Comment: Ошибки нет , нет ожидаемых данных

Comment: Users: 61, 62, 63; Deps: 11, 12,13; DepUsers: 61, 11, data; 61, 12, data; 61, 13, data; 62, 11, data. Хочу получить: 61, 11, 1; 61, 12, 1; 61,13, 1; 62, 11, 1; 62, 12, null; 62, 13, null; 63, 11, null, 63, 12, null; 63, 13, null

Comment: Покажите как Вы выводите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
SELECT 
T.user_id,
T.dep_id,
depusers.data 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        users.user_id, 
        deps.dep_id
    FROM users CROSS JOIN deps) AS T
LEFT JOIN depusers ON (T.user_id = depusers.user_id AND
T.dep_id = depusers.dep_id);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно...